# JQuery tablesorter custom sorter using textExtraction and textSorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a column that have both date and text data:

```
<td>
<div class="date">07/01/2016</div>
<div class="status">open</div>
</td>
```

I need to first sort the date, then within the same date, sort by the text of "status" div. Following code is what I have so far using textExtraction and textSorter option, but the column is not sorting. The strange thing I found out is, when I change the first row into:

```
<td><span class="date">07/31/2016</span><div class="status">open</div></td>
```

it was able to sort the rest of the table without the first row. Can anyone help? Thanks.  jsfiddle link ([here](http://jsfiddle.net/fatbrick/nk1qaq6v/15/))

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#articles-table').tablesorter({
    textExtraction:{
            2:function(node, table, cellIndex){
                var $n = $(node).find('div');
                return $.trim($n.eq(0).text())+";"+$.trim($n.eq(1).text());
                }
    },
    textSorter:{
        2:function(a, b){
                var aArr = a.split(";")[0].split('/');
                var bArr = b.split(";")[0].split('/');
                var aDate = aArr[2] + aArr[0] + aArr[1] + "";
                var bDate = bArr[2] + bArr[0] + bArr[1] + "";
                var result= aDate < bDate ? -1 : (aDate > bDate ? 1 : 0);
                 if (!result) { // Level 1 is equal
                    var sa = a.split(";")[1];
                    var sb = b.split(";")[1];
                    result = sa.localeCompare(sb);
                 }
                return result;
            }


    }
});

});
```

EDIT: Solved by adding class="sorter-text" on th to set sorter type as text.